# How do i get a subgraph independent of the internal structure?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I want to return a sub-graph that is attached to a certain vertex (Vertex 3). It should not matter how this sub-graph is structured in detail. Ultimately, all I want is to get the vertices and edges that make up the sub-graph.

[Simple graph with sub-graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qodv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [TinkerPop-modern sample graph](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graph-computing) you can do this with the following query:

```
graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
g = graph.traversal()
g.E(8).drop()   // Edge interferes with OP example graph

g.V(1).bothE().as('e').otherV().where(id().not(is(2))).repeat(
        bothE().where(neq('e')).subgraph('subGraph').otherV().simplePath()
    ).emit().times(4).cap('subGraph').
    next().traversal().V()
==>v[3]
==>v[4]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
```

Explanation:

- v(1) is the vertex connected to the subgraph to be found
- v(2) is your start vertex, to be excluded from the subgraph
- The edge between v(1) and the subgraph also needs to be excluded from the subgraph and gets a reference 'e'
- The repeat(...).emit().times(4) does the looping starting from the subgraph's initial edge(s)
- The where(neq('e')) makes sure v(1) is not included in the subgraph
- cap('subGraph') makes the traversal hold a TinkerGraph objects, created from all the edges referenced by subgraph('subGraph')
- next().traversal().V() returns the subgraph, creates a GraphTraversalSource from it and show all vertices in the subgraph

It does not seem possible to start the traversal from v(2), your start vertex, because gremlin's subgraph mechanism does not create separate subgraphs for different branches in the total graph but rather accumulates them in the global SideEffect referenced by 'subGraph'.